# ToggleClass with checkbox labels

Tags: jquery, css, toggleclass

I have a list of labels that when clicked, jQuery toggles the class on and off.

On each label there will be a different icon relating to what it is say in black. When the class is activated to say it's selected, a grey arrow overlays the label. What i need is to change the icon from black to white and this is where i am having problems.

Here is a quick jsfiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/vvvRX/

In my jQuery toggle, it toggles the active class called active but this is has the plain gray arrow on, how would i get it to show the gray arrow and the white icon for each label?

Would i have to do an if statement for each one instead of `$(this)` ?

Seems to be too many div's and classes floating about so i know there must be a solution to this!

Thanks.

Comment: Could you reformulate the excact question? I do not understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: where are your icons and what grey arrow are you talking about? I dont see either of those in your fiddle.

Comment: Yes sure i will just update my jsFiddle

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work at all on IE10

Comment: I think we're missing the icons in your jsfiddle example.

Comment: What are you asking? :D

Comment: I believe your issue is that you're trying to set two different backgrounds for the label at once. If you need to have a different CSS selector for when `#school` is active, you can combine the two like `#school.active`. (Whereas `#school` would select the inactive version.)

Comment: An updated version of my jsfiddle is added in the question. I have added some dummy images and used tinyuploads just as an example :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the background of an object to two different images.

If you want the icon to change on click, you can create a separate div to display the icon.

CSS:

```
.labelItem .icon {
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: right;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

#iconUniversity {
    background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/32/Business-Graduation-cap-icon.png') no-repeat;
}

.active #iconUniversity {
    background: url('http://www.maxwellplan.com/fw/img/university-check-icon-white.png') no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="university" class="checkbox" />
    <div class="labelItem">
        <label for="university">University</label>
        <div id="iconUniversity" class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/f8hVn/2/

You also seem to have the concepts of `id` and `class` confused. The `id` should be unique - you'd use the `id` if you need to differentiate between different objects of the same `class`. A `class` is something you should assign to multiple objects that you want to look the same. Objects can have more than one `class`, but only one `id`.

In this example, you should use a `class` for all of the bits and the backgrounds that are shared between the items. You should use an `id` for the icons which need to be different for each item.

Comment: This makes sense and i thanks for the id and classes, i have changed them so many times - yes my code is a mess from the updates and once applied i will update my jsFiddle so you's can see a working example. Thank you

Comment: The only issue here is that clicking on that div will not automatically check or uncheck the checkbox the way the label normally would. I updated the code and [here is a slightly better version](http://jsfiddle.net/av8zp/2/), but it's a little messy. Unless you need the actual checkboxes, you should probably just keep track of the objects' states with classes or as JavaScript objects.

Comment: I'd also recommend checking out Symbol/Icon fonts. You can use a font for your icons and have it automatically change colors with the text. See [the CSS Tricks Article "Icon Fonts are Awesome"](http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Well... you will need a white icon first of all :)

Then just add the following style for the `active` status:

```
.university.active{ 
    color:white; 
    margin-left:-12px;
    background: url('URL_WITH_WHITE_ICON') 210px center no-repeat;  
}
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/vvvRX/1/  (for the 2nd button)

Also, be careful, you are using the id `padding` more than once... it should be a class.

## UPDATE

If you want to keep the both backgrounds at the same time, then you are in trouble. You would need to make use of `:before` or `:after` properties, [which are not supported by older versions of many browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent)

Position relative for your labels:
    label {
        color:#40403e;
        background:#dbdcd4; 
          position:relative;
    }

And the `:after` style with the new background:

```
.university.active:after{ 
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    z-index:3;
    color:white; 
    right:-12px;
    top:-2px;
    background: url('http://www.maxwellplan.com/fw/img/university-check-icon-white.png') 210px center no-repeat ;   
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/vvvRX/3/

## UPDATE 2

Your main problem is your HTML code. It would be much more simple if you just had it properly created. For example, using a list for the items and adding an span element for the icon at the right. Then you could work separately with the list background or the span background for the active state.

Well, I am not gonna explain you everything but just take a look at how things should have been done:

http://jsfiddle.net/vvvRX/4/

Comment: beat me to it just have a link here to what i have! http://jsfiddle.net/dknhm/5/ My only issue is i need the grey arrow like the top one and the white icon. I can get a block bgcolour working but not the grey arrow image and white icon with them being two images. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Thanks for the help.. hmmm i wonder if theres a way i can do an if statement in jQuery rather than using :after i will look into this!

Comment: Your main problem is your HTML code. It would be much more simple if you just had it properly created. For example, using a list for the items and adding an `span` element for the icon at the right. Then you could work separately with the list background or the span background for the `active` state. Take a look at some proper sites and you will realize how these things are usually done.

Comment: The reason i have it like this is that it is implemented within a google map and toggles the markers as well as the labels. Apologies if i wasn't clear with my question...